# This Code keeps giving me errors, and i am new to classes

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm learning python 3 and am trying to learn classes. This code is giving me trouble. It's supposed to be for an very basic virtual pet:

```
class Critter(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    print("I am born")
    self.name = name
def talk (self, speech):
    pass
```

This is the start of the code, and seems to be error free. Then I have:

```
crit1 = Critter(input("Choose a name for me "))
crit2 = Critter(input("Choose a name for me "))
crit1.talk(speech = input("Hello. I am ", self.name, ". What shall I say? ")
        print("\n", speech))
crit2.talk(speech = input("Hello. I am ", self.name, ". What shall I say? ")
        print("\n", speech,))
```

This gives an error:

```
line 13
print("\n", speech))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I think your intendation may be faulty. Remember intendation is very important in python

Comment: Also you need to count your parentheses in and out...

Comment: [Here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). They'll be infinitely more helpful than we will be. Specifically, [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) will be very helpful to you for usage.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, also, your intendation seems to be faulty.
Try changing

```
class Critter(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    print("I am born")
    self.name = name
def talk (self, speech):
    pass
```

into

```
class Critter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("I am born")
        self.name = name
    def talk (self, speech):
        pass
```

Comment: I think that, with the way that their code is set up, the parenthesis to close the `talk` method call, is actually that one that you're proposing they remove. They just need to move it to before the `print` statement. EDIT: ah nvm you got it

Comment: Mind if I make an answer, or you wanna steal the glory? :P

Comment: @ElliotRoberts haha, go ahead. I will remove mine

Answer (score 0):

When you call `talk` here:

```
crit1.talk(speech = input("Hello. I am ", self.name, ". What shall I say? ")
        print("\n", speech))
```

You open another parentheses with `input` as well. Because of this, Python thinks you're still trying to pass arguments to `talk`. When passing arguments, you can't just have a line break and then something else without closing it, thus the syntax error on that line.

I would recommend that you close your call like so:

```
crit1.talk(speech = input("Hello. I am ", self.name, ". What shall I say? "))
```

And then have your print statement, without the extra parenthesis:

```
print("\n", speech)
```

Comment: Haven't done much python, but `print("\n", speech,)` is that really a thing? I am thinking of the two commas `,`

Comment: Nvm, seems to be a way of doing concatenations. Never seen comma `,` instead of plus `+` before

Comment: @Aidin `print` takes a variable number of positional arguments, think `*args` if you've seen it. It prints a new line followed by speech with a default separation of `' '`.

Comment: right you are, it doesn't break anything, the comma, but I've removed it 'cause it doesn't do anything